# Way to tell if an app is ASP.NET 1.1 or ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net

How can I tell if an App is ASP.NET 2.0 or ASP.NET 1.1. This is in C#

I don't have the source code and I  don't have access to IIS Manager. But I can ftp and check the ASPX files. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you can get an error message to show it will tell you at the bottom of the page what version of the framework is in use.

or, if you could upload a file, you could upload an aspx page containing code to output the framework version:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableSessionState="False" EnableViewState="False" Trace="False" Debug="False" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(System.Environment.Version);
}
</script>
```

this was just typed in, there could be syntax or other code errors.

Comment: This website is bulletproof. So robust. I could not crash it if I tried :D

Comment: just added another thing, maybe try that?

Comment: You could also temporarily enable tracing in web.config, then Trace.axd will include the framework version

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the DLL of the application.
2. Open them with Reflector
3. Analyse the dll and look for "Depends on"

If it tries to load System.dll (or any core type) you will be able to see which version of the core components it depends on.

Answer (score 2):

In 2.0, there was a change in the @Page directive to add the CodeFile attribute.

So, if you find that attribute, it's 2.0.

Comment: Similarly, if the .aspx.cs is a partial class then it must be 2.0. The catch with both is that the 1.1 way still works in 2.0, so you can't be sure that it's 1.1 if they're not there.

Comment: Good point, Steve. My suggestion was only one of many choices, and it's a quick test. You are assuming that the questioner has access to the .cs file, which seems to be part of the problem. He says he can only see the .aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just deliberately upload a test.aspx to cause an exception to be thrown; the default ASP.NET yellow screen of death will show the runtime version.

:-D

Comment: of course, no production application should let you see a yellow screen of death :)

Comment: Set debug="true" for a short while

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through your browser - just look in the response headers for "X-AspNet-Version"

In FireFox you can do this with the web developer toolbar... -> Information -> View Response Headers.

You can also check Response Headers with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/)

Or just use the ViewHtml website [here](http://www.viewhtml.com) to view Response Headers